# what how to get a node from an xml document using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not familiar with xml. I have an xml document structured like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:b xmlns="something">
  <a:c>
    <d>
      <e>
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item1</item>
       </e>
     </d>
   <a:c>
 <a:b>
```

I want to get the node "e" to retrieve its child items in my xslt as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="Product" select="document('itemList.xml')/node()[1]/node()[0]/node()[0]/node()[0]"/>
```

But it is not working. Kindly suggest the right way to do it. Also, is the first node refered by node()[0] or node()[1]? Links to articles for a good understanding of this node concept of xml are welcome.

Comment: Is the /node()[1]/node()[0]/node()[0]/node()[0] XPATH? I think maybe you can replace it with //item or else /a:b/a:c/d/e/item

Comment: Also you asked for links: http://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013 check out the videos of the querying XML section. Watch at least the XPATH and the XSLT video.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML doesn't have the prefix `a` bound to an URI. Assuming that is fixed.

```
a:b/a:c/x:d/x:e
```

will get you the node when x is bound to `something`

Comment: but to get all the children shouldn't you add a /item at the end there (or a /x:item)?

Comment: @Dan `x:e` provides the entire sub-tree. You'll have the `item` in it. When you have `/item` appended at last of your XPath, you'll be getting a list of `item` nodes, not `e`.

Comment: Yeah that's my interpretation of the OPs question though. Even though he says he wants node e I think he really wants a list of the item elements. He says he wants to retrieve the child elements of node e. Either way I'm sure this will get him to the right place. +1

Answer (score 0):

The XML you provided is not currently valid.  It has declared a default namespace, but has not declared the `a:` namespace.  It would need to start with something like this:

```
<a:b xmlns="something" xmlns:a="somethingElse">
```

If, in your XSLT, you declared the `a` namespace and associated the `something` namespace with the prefix `s`, you could access the `e` node with:

```
/a:b/a:c/s:d/s:e
```

If you want to access the nodes simply based on their position, you could do this, though this is not usually a very good practice:

```
/*[1]/*[1]/*[1]/*[1]
```

To answer your question, XPath is 1-index based, so the first item in any selection is accessed with [1].